# Adding CDN link to static folder of django

Tags: django

How can I add the cdn link for chart.js in html page to static folder so that I wont be dependent on cloudflare and I can cache it in my CloudFront distribution as well. can anyone help me on that.

Comment: You can download the js files from the github page.

Comment: of the chart.js library right?

Comment: yeah, chart.js or chart.min.js for the minified version (version without documentation)

Comment: I have the package folder now, should I just add it in the cache folder of django?